# Primitive value conversion

Tags: java, primitive-types

This is the snippet of code in Java:

```
int i = 1234567890;     
float f = i;    
System.out.println(i - (int)f);
```

Why is that the output is not equal to 0? It performs widening, so it is not supposed to loose data. Then you just truncate the value.
Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the difference

```
 int i = 1234567890;     
 float f = i;    
 System.out.println(i - f);
 System.out.println((int)f);
 System.out.println(f);
 System.out.println(i-(int)f);
```

Ouput:

```
0.0

1234567936

1.23456794E9

-46
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here:

> It performs widening, so it is not supposed to loose data.

This statement is wrong. Widening does not mean that you do not lose data.

From the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.2):

> Widening primitive conversions do not lose information about the **overall magnitude** of a numeric value.
>
> Conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, **may result in loss of precision** - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

Emphasis mine.

The specification clearly states that the *magnitude* is not lost, but *precision* can be lost.

The word *widening* refers not to the precision of a data type, but to its **range**. Floats are wider than ints because they have a larger range.

> **int**
>
> 4 bytes, signed (two's complement). -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
>
> **float**
>
> 4 bytes, IEEE 754. Covers a range from 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38 (positive or negative).

As you can see, `float` has a larger range. However some integers cannot be represented exactly as floats. This representation error is what causes your result to differ from 0. The actual value stored in f is 1234567936.

Comment: @Quoi: Yes, that's correct... and so does `(f == (float)i)`. And your point is... ?

Answer (score 0):

Widening can lose precision. An `int` has 32-bits of precision where as a `float` has a 25-bits of precision (a 24-bit mantissa and an implied top bit).  Java considers `float` to be wider than the 64-bit `long` which is a bit mad IMHO

With an 8-bit difference in precision, the error can be up to about +/-64 as it rounds the `int` value to the nearest `float` representation.

```
int err = 0;
for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; i > Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2; i--) {
    int err2 = (int) (float) i - i;
    if (Math.abs(err2) > err) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + err2);
        err = Math.abs(err2);
    }
}
```

prints

```
... deleted ...
2147483584: 63
2147483456: -64
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be shocked to find out that even this can be true:

```
(f==(f+1))==true
```

given `f` is a float large enough...

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1234567890;     
    float f = i;    
    System.out.println((int)f);
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i - (int)f);
```

output is:

```
1234567936
1234567890
-46
```

see the difference.

compare integer float have larger value.